# syntastic with python no warnings and error arrows

Tags: python, vim, syntastic

I have following [vimrc](https://github.com/mictadlo/vimrc4GO/blob/master/.vimrc), but I do not get arrows for warnings and error from syntastic[image]

like on the picture below [image]

Further more I am not able to use the ruler with **set ruler**. Why I do not get a warning that variable "a" is not used?

What did I do wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntastic is checking your code for compliance with [PEP8.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). This is a recommendation usually followed by the Python community around formatting your code.

- The first error is because you did `import os` but then you don't actually call any methods from `os` in your code since that line is commented out.  You shouldn't import modules you don't use.
- The second is because PEP8 specifies that you should have [2 blank lines between the imports and the start of your code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines).
- The third is because PEP8 also says there should be no trailing whitespace.

As far as the ruler goes, I'm not exactly sure as to what you're referring.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but I do not get the warning and error signs like these https://raw.github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/master/_assets/screenshot_1.png ? Why I do not get a warning that variable "a" is not used and I am not able to use the ruler with **set ruler**.?

Comment: @user977828: The example screenshot is from checking C code. The output for Python warnings and errors will be different from the output for C code.

Comment: Yes, you right, but if I understand syntastic correct it should also provide for Python signs which are placed beside lines with errors ( warnings are displayed in a different color).

Comment: ruler is working now, but I did not get signs which are placed beside lines with errors.